# C++ operators precedence

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, operator-precedence

I am using this statement

```
if ((pm && pn) || (pm == false && pn == false))
```

it is supposed to return true only if both pm and pn are true or if both are false. But this is also returning true if only only first one (pm) is true.

So now it is acting like this:

```
0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 1
1 1 = 1
```

but I need it to work like this:

```
0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 1
```

can you tell me where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is simply:

```
if (pm == pn)
```

Comment: Only if the variables already have `bool` type, or are otherwise guaranteed only to take one possible non-zero value.

Comment: Many thanks. This is best solution. Dont know why I didnt saw it

Comment: I was assuming they where known to be of type `bool`, if not simply code: `if (!pm == !pn)`

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if `pm` is true twice. You also need to check if both are the same, not whether they are both true. So,

```
if ((pm == pn) 
        ^^ ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pm && pm
```

should be

```
pm && pn
       ^
```

The whole expression can be simplified to

```
pm == pn
```

if the variables already have `bool` type.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try xor?

```
if (!(pm ^ pn)) { /*...*/ }
```

Or simply equal?

```
if (pm == pn) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if ((pm && pm) || (pm == false && pn == false))
> ```
>
> it is supposed to return true only if both pm and pn are true or if both are false. But this is also returning true if only only first one (pm) is true.

Because you made a typo. You meant `pm && pn`.

Instead just write `if (pm == pn)`, which is equivalent along as the only semantic values are indeed `true` and `false` for both variables.

Plus, consider making your variable names clearer and more distinct.

Note that operator precedence has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question's title asks about precedence, note that `||` has lower precedence than `&&`. So the two sets of inner parentheses are redundant, and the original expression is just a longer way of saying

```
if (pm && pm || pm == false && pn == false)
```

Now, fixing the obvious typo:

```
if (pm && pn || pm == false && pn == false)
```

Removing the unneeded explicit comparisons:

```
if (pm && pn || !pm && !pn)
```

And, finally, a less obvious transformation, which others have suggested:

```
if (pm == pn)
```